# Make -j Failing for OQS Openssl

Tags: command-line, software-installation, make

I am not a developer.

I am trying to build the [Open Quantum Safe (OQS) variant of OpenSSL](https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/openssl) using an Ubuntu VM.

Everything worked great up until the last step where I do "make -j", where I am getting fatal errors. Examples of the fatal errors are

```
  In file included from include/openssl/x509.h:18,

  from apps/apps.c:29:

  include/openssl/evp.h:18:11: fatal error: oqs/oqs.h: No such file or directory

  18 | # include <oqs/oqs.h>

  |           ^~~~~~~~~~~

  compilation terminated.
```

I have tried several things, but just cannot past it, for example, checking that the system has openssl (openssl version = OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022))

Any ideas of how to correct these fatal errors?

Comment: the OQS library was not properly installed

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David: it is release 22.10, kinetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OQS library was not properly installed, to fix that you gonna have to follow these steps, first we install the needed dependencies

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential git cmake python3 libssl-dev
```

Then we clone the `liboqs` repo

```
git clone https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs.git
```

we install it

```
cd liboqs
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -GNinja -DOQS_USE_OPENSSL=1 ..
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

Then we clone the `OQS-OpenSSL` repo

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/openssl.git
```

then we build it

```
cd openssl
./Configure shared --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl linux-x86_64
make -j
```

Normaly it should work, if not try

```
./Configure shared --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl linux-x86_64 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
make -j
```

then we install it `sudo make install`

last we update the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

edit:

You should have `liboqs.so` present in /usr/local/lib, if not there there was a problem with the install of OQS library.
Run the `./Configure` command

```
cd ~/openssl
./Configure shared --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl linux-x86_64 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -DOQS_DIR=/usr/local
```

then

```
make -j
```

then we try `sudo make install`

Comment: It got much further, but had an issue on "sudo make install", with "No OQS library directory found to install. Exiting install with failure.

exit 1

make: *** [Makefile:454: install_runtime_libs] Error 1"

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: There is a liboqs.a, but no liboqs.so, even after the ./Configure command.

Comment: I do not think there was anything wrong with what you wrote or with what I did, I think there is an issue with the code base. I loaded the newer Docker image and that worked, although I am still working through all that newness. I will accept your answer - thanks for the help!