Openssl build fails for LIBOQS library
I have tried steps suggested in this thread "https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462945/make-j-failing-for-oqs-openssl" but without luck and i am getting these errors and I am posting last few line of the build as below:
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/liboqs.a(ossl_helpers.c.o): in function `free_ossl_objects':
ossl_helpers.c:(.text.free_ossl_objects+0xc8): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_free'
/usr/bin/ld: ossl_helpers.c:(.text.free_ossl_objects+0xdf): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_free'
/usr/bin/ld: ossl_helpers.c:(.text.free_ossl_objects+0xf6): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_free'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/liboqs.a(ossl_helpers.c.o): in function `fetch_ossl_objects':
ossl_helpers.c:(.text.fetch_ossl_objects+0x14): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_fetch'
/usr/bin/ld: ossl_helpers.c:(.text.fetch_ossl_objects+0x2b): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_fetch'
/usr/bin/ld: ossl_helpers.c:(.text.fetch_ossl_objects+0x42): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_fetch'
/usr/bin/ld: ossl_helpers.c:(.text.fetch_ossl_objects+0x59): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_fetch'
/usr/bin/ld: ossl_helpers.c:(.text.fetch_ossl_objects+0x70): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_fetch'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/liboqs.a(ossl_helpers.c.o):ossl_helpers.c:(.text.fetch_ossl_objects+0x87): more undefined references to `EVP_MD_fetch' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/liboqs.a(ossl_helpers.c.o): in function `fetch_ossl_objects':
ossl_helpers.c:(.text.fetch_ossl_objects+0xcc): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_fetch'
/usr/bin/ld: ossl_helpers.c:(.text.fetch_ossl_objects+0xe3): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_fetch'
/usr/bin/ld: ossl_helpers.c:(.text.fetch_ossl_objects+0xfa): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_fetch'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:9175: test/siphash_internal_test] Error 1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:9058: test/rdrand_sanitytest] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/umadevi/openssl'
make: *** [Makefile:175: all] Error 2

I have ubuntu 22.04LTS version and openssl Version OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022.
Please help and I have installed liboqs already.
